# Dynamically Sized View based on Child View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a custom view controller used as a child view controller:

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
    }
    

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        calculatePreferredSize()
    }
    
    
    func calculatePreferredSize() {
        let targetSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width,
                                height: UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize.height)
        preferredContentSize = view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize)
    }
}
```

then in the main view controller, I have this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var container : UIView!
    var childVC   : ChildViewController!
    
    var containerHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .purple
        
        // setup container to hold child vc
        container = UIView()
        container.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
        view.addSubview(container)
        container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

        containerHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
        containerHeightConstraint = container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        containerHeightConstraint.isActive = true
        
        // setup child vc
        childVC = ChildViewController()
        addChild(childVC)
        container.addSubview(childVC.view)
        childVC.view.frame = container.bounds
        childVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        // add contents into the child vc
        let newView = UIView()
        childVC.view.addSubview(newView)
        newView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newView.superview!.topAnchor),
            newView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newView.superview!.leadingAnchor),
            newView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newView.superview!.trailingAnchor),
            newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 123),
        ])
    }
   
    
    override func preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer) {
        super.preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer: container)
        if (container as? ChildViewController) != nil {
            containerHeightConstraint.constant = container.preferredContentSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to dynamically size the `container` view in the main VC based on the child's calculated height.  The `preferredContentSizeDidChange` method is being called but in my calculation of the child VC's height (using `UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize`), I'm always getting back 0.  Even though I've checked the frame of the view added onto that view and it has the correct frame height (in this example, 123).  As shown in the output logging below:

```
(lldb) po view.subviews
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : <UIView: 0x12251cd40; frame = (0 0; 350 123); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000007a0e60>>

(lldb) po UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize
▿ (0.0, 0.0)
  - width : 0.0
  - height : 0.0
```

Below is a screenshot from the simulator.

[image]

Am I using the `UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize` incorrectly?  How do I calculate the height of the child view based on its contents?

Comment: Does your child view controller has appropriate autolayout constraints set? Can it actually evaluate proper height in your `calculatePreferredSize` method? `systemLayoutSizeFitting` calculates the minimum size need to satisfy all the constraints can you put a break point and check what do you return at the end of `calculatePreferredSize` method?

Comment: Hi.  Sorry but I actually answer all of that in the question.  1. Yes constraints are set for the `newView`. 2. No it can't - that's why I'm asking the question. 3. Yes I've done that and included the logging output.  The frame is there with the correct dimensions (e.g. width of 350 and height of 123) but yet `systemLayoutSizeFitting` doesn't calculate it correctly. Assume I'm calling it in the wrong sequence or something because the subviews are there and even visible on screen at the correct size.

Comment: `UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize` will always be `(0, 0)` because it's a constant.

Comment: @JurajBlahunka - thanks but I don't think that's correct.  See Apple documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622624-systemlayoutsizefitting or this video at the 37:30 mark https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/220/

Comment: Correct, `UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize` is the guidance (target size), for the `systemLayoutSizeFitting` method. It will not get modified by the method. What you need to inspect is the return value of the `systemLayoutSizeFitting` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autolayout can't calculate the `newView` content height, because it is missing constraints in the Y axis to solve the equation.

`newView` has only these constraints defined: top, leading, trailing and height.
It is missing the bottom constraint:

```
newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newView.superview!.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

The full set of constraints would look like the following:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newView.superview!.topAnchor),
    newView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newView.superview!.leadingAnchor),
    newView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newView.superview!.trailingAnchor),
    newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 123),
    newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newView.superview!.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Afterwards when I place a breakpoint into `preferredContentSizeDidChange`, I can print the `container.preferredContentSize.height`, which is `123.0`.

**EDIT**
To avoid constraint breakage, we also need to use autolayout for `childVC.view`. Right now it is using autosizing mask, which only flows from top-down and creates constraints with 1000 priority.

```
childVC.view.frame = container.bounds
```

needs to be replaced with

```
childVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    childVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor),
    childVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor),
    childVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor),
    childVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor)
])
```

and the `containerHeightConstraint` needs to have a reduced priority for the 0 height constraint, otherwise the system will always find the constraints ambiguous - the child controller wants to be 123 points tall, but the container height constraint is still at 0 before we call the `preferredContentSizeDidChange` method.

```
containerHeightConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
```

Comment: I'm clearly not understanding something.  Adding that 5th constraint causes an unsatisfiable auto layout logging error because the view does already have a height set - 123, so it can't be anchored to both the top anchor and the bottom anchor of it's parent view.  Sorry, but maybe I'm not understanding something here.

Comment: Adding the above, does calculate the `preferredContentSizeDidChange` but I think this isn't the right approach still as it causes auto layout to have to break a constraint.  and in this case it breaks the height constraint so the end result is now a child view controller with a height of 0 when checking the Debug View Hierarchy in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks.  Whilst the simulator now displays correctly, there are still auto layout constraint errors because we now have `newView` with constraints to all edges of its parent view as well as having a height of 123.  I also don't really understand the need to have constraints 5 constraints for `newView`.  But I appreciate your help.

Comment: Looking at this some more - I'll give you another example.  If I move the `newView` code and constraints into the Child VC, and then instantiate that view controller as a main view controller, now the blue view fills up the entire screen because we've anchored it to all edges.  That's why I though the original constraints I had are the way to go - keeps the correct height at 123, and has the blue `newView` at the top.  But when embedded as a child VC, then we calculate the content size of that VC using `systemLayoutSizeFitting` and `UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize`

Comment: I think the best thing at this point is to re-frame your question and perhaps ask about the underlying concepts separately? This thread is getting out of scope of the original question.

Comment: My question is the same... how to get systemLayoutSizeFitting and UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize working. The proposed solution of adding a bottom constraint creates auto layout constraint errors.

Comment: If you try the above fixes, you should be able to clean out any autolayout constraint errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228765/discussion-between-anthony-and-juraj-blahunka).